# Best way to add space around a ColumnLayout?

Tags: qt, qml

I like that there is a `spacing` property to add space between items in a layout. But is it also possible to add space around a layout?

See my code below. I try to use `anchors.margins` on the `ColumnLayout` but that does not work.

```
Rectangle {
    id: leftSelectionRect
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.right: leftLine.left
    implicitWidth: leftSelectionLayout.implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: leftSelectionLayout.implicitHeight
    color: CustomProperties.Colors.transparentSelectionBackground

    ColumnLayout {
        id: leftSelectionLayout
        spacing: CustomProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.margins: CustomProperties.Margins.small // This is what I would like to do, but it does not work.

        CustomComponents.HeaderText {
            id: leftText
            text: Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.startUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)

        }

        CustomComponents.HeaderText {
            id: leftdeltaText
            text: "Δ " + Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.deltaUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)

        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT*

The following is the first attempt I have made that works, but it is messy. There must be a better way:

```
Rectangle {
    id: leftSelectionRect
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.right: leftLine.left
    implicitWidth: leftSelectionLayout.implicitWidth + CustomProperties.Margins.medium * 2
    implicitHeight: leftSelectionLayout.implicitHeight + CustomProperties.Margins.small * 2
    color: CustomProperties.Colors.transparentSelectionBackground

    ColumnLayout {
        id: leftSelectionLayout
        spacing: CustomProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.topMargin: CustomProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.bottomMargin: CustomProperties.Margins.small
        anchors.leftMargin: CustomProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.rightMargin: CustomProperties.Margins.medium
        anchors.fill: parent

        CustomComponents.HeaderText {
            id: leftText
            text: Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.startUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)

        }

        CustomComponents.HeaderText {
            id: leftdeltaText
            text: "Δ " + Converter.formatDuration(ui.selectionModel.deltaUs, Converter.MicroSeconds, Converter.MicroSeconds)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that should work, given that `CustomProperties.Margins.small` is a numerical value. Or maybe you should add `anchors.fill: parent`?

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried exchanging CustomProperties.Margins.small for an integer value but it made no difference. Adding anchors.fill: parent to ColumnLayout also did not help.

Comment: @Amfasis: See my edit if you have time

Comment: For me it really works, however I replaced `CustomComponent.HeaderText` with a simple `Button`. Maybe you have to set the `implicitWidth`/`Height` for that `HeaderText`?

Answer (score 0):

Do not add `anchors.fill:parent` to your inner `ColumnLayout` but to your outer wrapper component:

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 10

    ColumnLayout {
        id: layout
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 10
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
        }
    }
}
```

At all you should avoid setting `height` property or `anchors.top` AND `anchors.bottom` properties to your `ColumnLayout` because it calculates its height at its own.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! But I can't set anchors.fill:parent on the surrounding Item. That item should not fill its parent.

Comment: @user1283776 Mh...you can still wrap the surrounding item into another component which has special `width` and `height` set. Can you provide a screenshot to show what you are trying to achive?

Comment: IMHO you should not add anchors to the root item of a qml, because you will probably be setting it wherever you use it (and thus creating a warning)